# SQL Server : adding complex rownumber

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

[image]

I was wondering if someone knows how I can get the missing results from the 2nd column ("As-IS-Rownumber", which are yellow). As example which shows the desired outcome, I added the 1st column("To-Be - Desired"). 
BTW I work with MS SQL.

I want a rownumber based on the columns KlantID and Repeat. However, when I use `partition by`, `rank` or `dense_rank`, I don't get the desired outcome, because of my last column.

I hope some1 can help me out.

### DDL

```
create table tbl (
    ToBeSubRow INT,
    AsIsSubrow INT,
    Rownumber INT,
    KlantID INT,
    Repeat CHAR(3)
)

insert  tbl (ToBeSubRow, AsIsSubrow, Rownumber, KlantID, Repeat)
values  (1,1,1,1,'NO'),
        (2,null,2,1,'YES'),
        (3,null,3,1,'YES'),
        (1,1,4,1,'NO'),
        (2,null,5,1,'YES'),
        (1,1,5,2,'NO'),
        (2,null,6,2,'YES'),
        (3,null,7,2,'YES')
```

Thanks 
Martijn

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IRGo.png)

Comment: which database is it ? title says `MSSQL` tag says `MySQL`

Comment: ms sql server 2014

Comment: Not clear to me.  Post text data, desired outcome, and a better problem statement.

Comment: Also, why are there 2 rows with the value `5` for `Rownumber`? Is this a typo?

Comment: -Larnu, you are correct. This is a typo.

Comment: Paparazzi, I added a new picture. This picture shows 2 tabels. Tabel 1 shows the situation what I have at this point and Tabel 2 shows the situation what I need. The fields in column 2 should be populated as shown in Tabel 2. This is based on the combination of column KlantID and Repeat. So the count should start at each new customer Id and where Repeat is equal to "No".

Comment: Please post the query that uses ROW_NUMBER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This keys on Repeat only
If a new `KlantID` does not start on `no` it breaks

```
declare @T table (Rownumber INT,  Subrow INT, Unq INT, KlantID INT, Repeat CHAR(3));
insert @T (Rownumber, Subrow , Unq , KlantID , Repeat) 
values (1, null, 1   , 1, 'NO'), 
       (2, null, null, 1, 'YES'), 
       (3, null, null, 1, 'YES'), 
       (4, null, 2,    1, 'NO'), 
       (5, null, null, 1, 'YES'), 
       (6, null, 1,    2, 'NO'), 
       (7, null, null, 2, 'YES'), 
       (8, null, null, 2, 'YES');
with CTEno as
( select T.Rownumber 
       , ROW_NUMBER() over (order by T.Rownumber) as r4 
    from @T T
   where T.Repeat = 'No'
)
select t.*
     , ISNULL(n.r4, (select top 1 n.r4 from CTEno n where n.Rownumber < t.Rownumber order by n.r4 desc)) as grp 
     , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by (ISNULL(n.r4, (select top 1 n.r4 from CTEno n where n.Rownumber < t.Rownumber order by n.r4 desc))) 
                          order by T.Rownumber) grpRow 
  from @T T 
  left join CTEno N
    on T.Rownumber = N.Rownumber 
 order by T.Rownumber;
```

Comment: At least it looks impressive :). I hope, I can test it within the hour or so. I will be back. Thanks so far for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a column to use as a Group ID, like this:

```
--Add a column called Group_ID
ALTER TABLE ASIS ADD GROUP_ID INT NULL

--Populate Group_ID
UPDATE  ASIS
SET     Group_ID = CASE Rownumber WHEN 1 THEN 1
                        WHEN 2 THEN 1
                        WHEN 3 THEN 1
                        WHEN 4 THEN 2
                        WHEN 5 THEN 2
                        WHEN 6 THEN 3
                        WHEN 7 THEN 3
                        WHEN 8 THEN 3
                        END


--Use Row_Number() to get the values you desire
SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Group_ID ORDER BY Rownumber) SubRow2
FROM    ASIS
```

Comment: That is just hard coding an answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but it shows the OP why they need an ID for the group if they are going to do this for millions of rows.  It's not as impressive as your solution though.  :)

Comment: I need an ID :). It will be executed for a few million records. At the moment I can't test the solution of Paparazzi. At least it looks impressive :). I hope, I can test it within the hour or so. I will be back. Thanks so far for all the help!